# Relationships with Spree::Products

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce, spree

I'm using Spree in my Rails 3.2 app and I'd like to know how can I create relationships between some models I'have defined myself and `Spree::Product`.

For example, in a clothing store I'd like do group products (`Spree::Product`) by Collection (now `Collection` is a hypothetical model of mine).

How do I declare a `has_many` relationship in `Collection` in respect to `Spree::Product` objects?

P.S: I've tried both `has_many :products` and `has_many :spree_products` within my model and none of them works.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to define this method on `Spree::Product` objects then you will need to use a decorator. Add this code to `app/models/spree/product_decorator.rb` within your application:

```
Spree::Product.class_eval do
  has_many :collections
end
```

Now each `Spree::Product` object will respond to a `collections` method.

Comment: Well, ok but what if I want to declare a `has_many` relationship in my Collection model like `has_many :products`?

Comment: `belongs_to :collection` && `has_many :spree_products, :class_name => "Spree::Product"` should work right?